# SQL output is coming as special character

Tags: sql

I am using the below script to get output. however i am getting 2 output in letter like #####. actually it should be integer numbers. Also other 2 day columns are not displaying time values
Can any one help me on this to find the correct value?

```
user="aguser"
pass="aguser"
dbname=`echo $LOGNAME|awk '{print substr($0,length($0) - 3)}'`
sql=" SELECT wrk.WO_ID , srq.CSDL_SEQ_NO, srq.ASDL_CMD, srq.HOST_CLLI As NEP, min(srq.START_DTS) as start_dt, max(srq.COMP_DTS) as comp_dt, ((max(srq.COMP_DTS)-min(srq.
START_DTS)) * 86400) as proc_time FROM SARMPRD1.TBL_ASDL_LOG srq, sarmprd1.tbl_wrk_ord wrk where srq.srq_id = wrk.srq_id and to_char(srq.start_dts,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24')=to
_char((sysdate-1/24), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24') and wrk.WO_STAT = '104' group by wrk.WO_ID, srq.SRQ_ID, srq.ASDL_UNID, srq.CSDL_SEQ_NO, srq.ASDL_CMD,HOST_CLLI order by proc_ti
me desc"
```

Current Output:

```
282685884BG      ########## A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     04-DEC-13              04-DEC-13              ##########
282686035BJ      ########## A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     04-DEC-13              04-DEC-13              ##########
282686105BG      ########## A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     04-DEC-13              04-DEC-13              ##########
282686106BI      ########## A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     04-DEC-13              04-DEC-13              ##########
```

expected out:

```
282685884BG      10 A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     12/4/2013 9:03:58 AM            12/4/2013 9:07:27 AM              18
282686035BJ      5  A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     12/4/2013 9:03:58 AM            12/4/2013 9:07:27 AM              240
282686105BG      5  A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     12/4/2013 9:03:58 AM            12/4/2013 9:07:27 AM              330
282686106BI      5  A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     12/4/2013 9:03:58 AM            12/4/2013 9:07:27 AM              4440
```

Comment: are you running this from ``sh``?

Comment: yes....this is shell script...

Comment: Do you have to use ``sh``? maybe its better to either feed the SQL directly into mysql/psql/etc client and capture the output. Or write a small PHP/Perl/etc script that does the same as the above code?